# Show CSV format in MS Excel open file dialog by default

Tags: microsoft-excel, default-settings, dialog, microsoft-excel-365

When opening files from within Excel using the Open file dialog and browsing to my data, the default setting is to list `"All Excel Files (*.xl*;*.xlsx;<etc>)"`. However, this listing of options does not include the commonly used (almost exclusively for me, anyway) CSV format. This is remedied by changing the extension list to `"All Files (*.*)"` or `"Text Files (*.prn;*.txt;*.csv)"` or something similar.

This is a fairly quick, 2 click process, but having to do it every time I open the application eventually wastes a lot of time. Is there a way to set the default open type to one of the CSV-friendly options, or anything else for that matter?

If it matters, I'm currently using Office365 on Windows, but I've dealt with this in 2016, 2013, 2010, etc. basically forever. Also, just in case it needs to be mentioned, I have no trouble opening and accessing/saving the files, either through Excel or from outside/via Windows. The problem is just in the *default* settings for this dialog.

Comment: Instead of using the Excel Provided File Open dialog, write your own in VBA.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I could do that, yes, but I was hoping for a more standard, "official" solution. :)